# Concrete 5 Email Sending issue to Google App

Tags: php, email, google-apps, concrete5, php-5.6

I am sending email from "Concrete 5" to Google App email address, but its not working, i also set up the "SMTP" settings but getting this error..

> **ERROR I AM RECEIVING WHILE TESTING IS :**

[image]

> The SMTP SETTING I HAVE DONE IS ALL RIGHT.. THE SETTING I ALSO BELOW

[image]

PLEASE SOME ONE TELL ME TO HOW TO FIX THIS ISSUE..

**I am in great trouble.. please help me...**

Thanks in adavnce

Comment: No reply from stackoverflow.. nobody knows about such issue..:(

Comment: Did you try TLS instead of SSL?

Comment: Also, in order to send emails via the Gmail SMTP server, the sender address must be one verified by Gmail